# Calculus Made Easy -Exercises IX, Question 10 (rates of change)

Tags: calculus

I am working with this exercise, which should be pretty easy, as a similar one is exemplified in the book.

> 10. A spherical balloon is increasing in volume. If, when its radius is r feet, its volume is increasing at the rate of 4 cubic feet per second, at what rate is its surface then increasing?

This is what i did: the formula for the volume of a sphere is $\ \frac43^3\;$.

Rate of change of volume with respect to time is 4, so $$\frac{dv}{dr}\cdot\frac{dr}{dt} = 4\implies 4r^2\cdot\frac{ dr}{dt} = 4$$, and $$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{r^2}.$$

As what is being asked is rate of change of surface area, I need to calculate now $\dfrac{dS}{dr} \cdot\dfrac{ dr}{dt}$. Surface area of a sphere is $4r^2$, its derivative with respect to $r$ is $8r$, and multiplied with the previously found $\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{r^2}$, it gives a result of $\dfrac{8}{r}$.

When I check the solutions of the book -rather bare, with no steps- it says the answer should be 8 times the square root of .

What have I done wrong?

Comment: IMO you are right; for sphere $\dfrac {dV}{dS}=\dfrac r 2$. Thus, $\dfrac {dS}{dt}=\dfrac {dV}{dt} \dfrac 2 r$.

Comment: You didn't say which edition, so I wondered whether this was an earlier edition's typo that was corrected later. However, [p. 175 of the 1910 1st edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=EccDugXNP5oC&pg=PA175) has $\frac{8}{r}$ and [p. 292 of the 1914 2nd edition](https://archive.org/details/CalculusMadeEasy/page/n305/mode/2up) also has $\frac{8}{r}.$ There's also a 3rd edition (1916?), but I wasn't able to find a copy of that edition to look at. Anyway, whatever edition/printing you're looking at, the error was introduced later by someone else.

Comment: Hi there! The edition I am reading is the 1998 one published by St. Martin's Press, New York and updated by Martin Gardner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  The answer in the book cannot be correct since it has the wrong units for the rate at which the surface area is changing.

Setting up the problem in a different way:
\begin{align*}
V & = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\\
\frac{dV}{dt} & = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}\\
\frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \frac{dV}{dt} & = \frac{dr}{dt}\\
\frac{1}{4\pi r^2} 4~\frac{\text{ft}^3}{\text{s}} & = \frac{dr}{dt}\\
\frac{1}{\pi r^2}~\frac{\text{ft}^3}{\text{s}} & = \frac{dr}{dt}
\end{align*}
We will substitute this result into the rate at which the surface area is changing.
\begin{align*}
S & = 4\pi r^2\\
\dfrac{dS}{dt} & = 8\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}\\
               & = 8\pi r \cdot \frac{1}{\pi r^2}~\frac{\text{ft}^3}{\text{s}}\\
               & = \frac{8}{r}~\frac{\text{ft}^3}{\text{s}}
\end{align*}
The units make sense since $r$ is measured in feet, leaving us with units of $\text{ft}^2/\text{s}$ for the rate at which the surface area is changing.

The units in the book's answer do not make sense since the lack of an $r$ in the denominator would mean that the units for $dS/dt$ would be $\text{ft}^3/\text{s}$.

Comment: Hi, I think your answer is exactly the same as what the OP has done. Also, do you think a dV/dt should be inserted in the LHS of the third line of your working?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thank you for pointing out the omission.  What I did is equivalent to what the OP did.  Clearly, it is not exactly the same.  Also, unit analysis shows that the OP was correct, while the answer in the book must be wrong.

Comment: Ah I see. You included the units. Ok fine